# Problema con IsMdiContainer

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo 1 formulario padre (por asi decirlo el menu) y un formulario hijo (formulario empleados) usando la propiedad en el padre IsMdiContainer=true y codificando en la pestaña empleado (evento click) el siguiente codigo:

```
        Ventana_empleados ir_a_emplead = new Ventana_empleados();
        ir_a_emplead.MdiParent = this;
        ir_a_emplead.Show();
```

se supone que con ese código se debe mostrar el formulario hijo dentro del padre de la siguiente manera:

---------ejecutando programa------------------
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-------oprimiendo pestaña empleados---------------
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver el formulario hijo (empleados) se desajusta por completo de sus dimensiones, ni maximizando la pestaña se logra ajustar proporcionalmente al formulario padre.

-------------------formulario hijo (empleados) con dimensiones originales-------
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿que estoy haciendo mal? porque se desajustan las dimensiones de cada elemento de mi formulario hijo cuando ejecuto el programa.

Comment: Para realizar esto tienes un Contenedor MDI que de preferencia para realizar lo que solicitas y/o una propiedad del Formulario activa esa modalidad ..

Comment: por lo que veo en tus Formularios el Form Padre activa los ScrollBar para que puedas subir/bajar ir a la Izq/der por que el Form Hijo no cabe .. puedes colocar una Imagen de tu Form padre Maximizada con el form hijo abierto ?

Comment: Lo pude resolver gracias, era por el estado de una propiedad, estaba en:  AutoScaleMode: font  y deberia estar en AutoScaleMode:Inherit Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para todos aquellos que tengan ese mismo problema se resuelve:
En el formulario hijo en mi caso la ventana empleado, cuenta con una propiedad (la podemos encontrar en el cuadro de propiedades) llamada **AutoScaleMode** esa propiedad hay que ponerla en **Inherit**
es decir:

*AutoScaleMode: Inherit*

Gracias a los que se tomaron el tiempo de contestar.